# Question about Bézout's Lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm somewhat confused about the following: Let $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $\gcd(a,c)=1$ so that by Bézout there are integers $m_1,n_1,m_2,n_2$ s.t. $$m_1a-n_1b=1,\quad m_2a-n_2c=1 \, .$$

Obviously we can make the simultaneous replacements for instance $m_1 \rightarrow m_1 + k_1 b$ and $n_1 \rightarrow n_1 + k_1 a$ that don't change the result for any integer $k_1$. Similarly this can be done for the second equation. This implies there are infinitely many such integer pairs. Now fixing $m_1$ and $n_1$, apparently we can always choose $m_2=m_1$. Why?

Comment: Says who? Take $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=9$. Then I write $2a-b = 1$. You say we can write $1=2a-9n_2$ for some $n_2$, but that would require $9n_2=2a-1 = 3$. This equation has no integer solution. The asserted “we can always choose” is false as written.

Comment: I don't know... He says it somewhere at 5min into the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3oL2DBtg14&t=296s

Comment: Actually he says there are infinitely many, so maybe it is not true for every $(m_1,n_1)$, but still for "enough" tuples.

Comment: You jumped me too far ahead, and I don't really feel like watching the entire thing. He only seems to need at least one solution of the form $ma+nb=1$, $ma+rc=1$ (that is, the same coefficient for $a$ in both), not that you can pick what the coefficient for $a$ will be (provided it works for $b$) and use *that* for $c$. There's certainly infinitely many ways to find $m,n,r$ as above, since there is at least one. It's just that not *every* solution to $ma+nb=1$ can then be used to find $r$ for $ma+rc=1$.

Comment: He expresses it very poorly. He does indeed make it seem like you can first find some $m$ and $n$ for $a$ and $b$, and then go ahead and find $r$ for $c$. That is definitely  not the case, even though you *can* find, by working with all three of $a$, $b$, and $c$, infinitely many triples $m,n,r$ that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asserted property is false.

Take a counterexample: $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=9$. Then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1$. We can express the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$ as:
$$1 = 2a -b = 2(2) - 3.$$
The asserted claim is that we can express $1=\gcd(a,c)$ in the form
$$1= 2a-n_2c$$
for some integer $n_2$. But in this case, that would mean solving $1 = 4-9c$, and this equation has no solution: you would need $9c_2=3$.

What *is* true is that you can find expressions for both $\gcd(a,b)$ and $\gcd(a,c)$ where the coefficient of $a$ is the same (you can’t just decide what it will be). To verify this, note that since $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1$, then $\gcd(a,bc)=1$. Therefore, there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$ma + nbc = 1.$$
From this, you get equations $ma + (nc)b = 1$ and $ma + (nb)c = 1$. You can also replace $bc$ with $\mathrm{lcm}(b,c)$.